# Dynamic input fields with non dynamic input fields insert into two mysql tables not working

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

I have two tables in the database

**Table 1 - Orders**

```
 - id -Primary Key
 - name
 - date
```

**Table 2 - Products**

```
 - product_id - Primary Key
 - product
 - id - Foreign Key
```

I have **three input fields, Name, Date and Product**. The product input field is a dynamic input field.

what I am trying to do is name and date input field is insert them into the orders MYSQL table and the product dynamic input field insert the data into the product MYSQL table which is a child of the orders table, so the id numbers need to match.

I am not able to insert the data to the two sql tables,

Please if you could go through the below could and offer some help.

Also please note that I am very new to coding.

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //connect to db
    $mysqli = NEW MySQLi('localhost','root','','dbtest');

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $product = $_POST['product'];

    foreach($name AS $key => $value){

            $sql = "INSERT INTO orders(name, date) VALUES 
            ('". $mysqli->real_escape_string($value)."',
             '". $mysqli->real_escape_string($date[$key])."'
            )"; 

        $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);

        $newOrderId = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);

        if($insert){
           $sql2 = "INSERT INTO products(product) VALUES 
            ('". $mysqli->real_escape_string($product[$key])."')";

        $insert = $mysqli->query($sql2);
        }

        echo"<script language='javascript'>alert('successfully inserted')</script>";
        echo"<script>document.location='index.php';</script>";

    }

    $mysqli->close();
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e){
        //Variables
        var html = '<p /><div>Product: <input type="TEXT" name="product[]" id="childproduct"/> <a href="#" id="remove">X</a></div>';
        var maxRows = 5;
        var x = 1;

        //Add Rows to the form
        $("#add").click(function(e){
            if(x <= maxRows){
            $("#container").append(html);
            x++;
            }
        });

        //Remove rows from the from
        $("#container").on('click','#remove', function(e){

            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            x--;
        });

    });

</script>  
</head>

<body>
<form method="POST">
    <div id="">
        Name: <input type="TEXT" name="name[]" id="name"/>
    </div><p />
    <div id="">
        Date: <input type="TEXT" name="date[]" id="date"/>
    </div><p />
    <div id="container">
        Product: <input type="TEXT" name="product[]" id="product"/>
    <a href="#" id="add">Add More</a>
    </div><p />
    <p />
    <input type="SUBMIT" name="submit" />
</form>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are new to coding, I recommend learning how to query with prepared statements.  This way you won't have to re-learn how to query.

Comment: Why do you declare `$newOrderId` if you don't use it? Why are the name and date fields given array-type name attributes?

Comment: yes you are right I did not use it, where would I put $newOrderId in the $sql2 statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding you need to save a record in order table based on name and date, and then need to save multiple products in child table called "products" but you were looping on wrong variable "name" because you have only 1 "name" & "date" field but have multiple products. Please try to run the following code hopefully it will do the trick for you

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //connect to db
    $mysqli = NEW MySQLi('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbtest');

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $product = $_POST['product'];

    $name1 = current($name);
    $date1 = current($date);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO orders(name, date) VALUES 
            ('" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($name1) . "',
             '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($date1) . "'
            )";

    $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);

    $newOrderId = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);

    if ($insert) {
        foreach ($product AS $key => $value) {


            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO products(product) VALUES 
            ('" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($value) . "')";

            $insert = $mysqli->query($sql2);
        }

        echo"<script language='javascript'>alert('successfully inserted')</script>";
        echo"<script>document.location='index.php';</script>";
    }

    $mysqli->close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, I have tried your code but it only inserted the data for the name and date table, it did not insert the data for product table

Comment: You need to check this query I have also added "ID" in the insert query.
 $sql2 = "INSERT INTO products(product, id) VALUES 
            ('" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($value) . "', '" . $insert . "')";

Comment: Or you can just try to execute this $sql2 = "INSERT INTO products(product) VALUES 
            ('" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($value) . "')";

Comment: Unfortunately still did not pass through the product data

Comment: Have edit my answer to remove the "id" column from the insert query, try to execute above code now. Otherwise match the column with your table in MySQL database

Comment: I finally got it to work, I passed through $newOrderId in the statement,

Comment: $sql2 = "INSERT INTO products(product, id) VALUES 
            ('" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($value) . "',
             '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($newOrderId) . "'
            )";